# check null object in jquery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to loop through each key value `json` element and print it.but some of the keys has `null` values also.

Hence `$.each` is giving error `TypeError: obj is null`

I dont want to remove null keys from object and not want to print null object in `html` variable. I want to check for `null` object in `$.each` function

Fiddle Demo -> [http://jsfiddle.net/paxg89q0/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/paxg89q0/3/)

Code:

```
var s={"CategoryID":"1","Name":"TCS","ID":"23","Type":"Pay","AccountNo":"1234567890","Authenticator":"{\"EmailAddress\":\"dfgsdfgsdfg\",\"MobileNumber\":\"98-7698769\",\"UniqueID\":\"9876-8975657-6\"}","AddBill":null,"PartnerID":null,"ShortName":null,"Token":"8FB91DE6"};
var html;
$('div').html(getKeyValueJson(s));

function getKeyValueJson(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value == 'object') {
            getKeyValueJson(value);
        }
        else {
            html += '<label>' + key + '</label><label>' + value + '</label>';
        }
    });
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Just explicitly compare to `null` - note that `typeof null` is `object` in JavaScript.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/paxg89q0/5/

Comment: Note that each property value of that object is a primitive value anyway (sting or null). There is no reason to recursively call the function.

Comment: @ArunPJohny : i dont want to print `null` pair in `html`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/paxg89q0/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof null` returns `"object"`, so `null` values are being treated as objects.

Since it seems that you want to omit nulls entirely, you can explicitly test for null values at the start of your `$.each` callback:

```
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    if(value === null) { return; } // skip nulls

...
```

Answer (score 1):

In some instances, you may want to execute code if the value is null. Wrap your executable code with this statement:

if (myVal== null) {

}

This statement provides a way to execute code only if myVal is null.

Change your code:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n03cru58/)

```
 function getKeyValueJson(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        if(value)
        {
          if (typeof value == 'object') {
            getKeyValueJson(value);
            }
          else {
            html += '<label>' + key + '</label>' + value + '</label>'; 
           }
        }
    });
    return html;
}
```

Comment: `null` values should not get printed in `html`

Comment: Note that this will also omit `0` and `false` values, which you may be valid values that you do not want to skip!